# Release a Python application using MySQL Connector for database without the user having to install MySQL?

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector-python

I have created a CLI app in Python, a sort of library management system that uses a MySQL database to store records. If I wanted to release this as an installable app, could I do it without the end-user having to install MySQL on their own device, and going through the trouble of importing the database schema?

Note that the database is stored/hosted on the user's local machine and there is no web server interaction.

Comment: The only thing you need is the database driver, not the database itself.

Comment: @gargantuan You need to have MySQL installed on the local machine, or on the network it's connected to. If you didn't already know that you are short of sufficient understanding of your environment and shouldn't consider releasing your app at this point.

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular I understood that, I was wondering if there is any way or alternative solution to deploy something like this.
I'm a highschool student only learning MySQL/Python now, not really planning on releasing a production-ready app yet :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't possible using a DBMS like Mysql, Postgres, Mariadb. That is what SQLite is for. All you need for a SQLite database is to install the connector, form there the rest is handled.

Check out this example of database creation and querying.

```
import sqlite3

connection = sqlite3.connect("test")

cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE example (name TEXT, type TEXT, count INTEGER)")
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO example VALUES ('Sammy', 'shark', 1)")
rows = cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM example").fetchall()
print(rows)
```

You do **not** need to install the `sqlite3` package with `pip`. As mentioned by a commenter, the package comes pre-installed with python.

Hope this helps!

Comment: [sqlite3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html) is an included package, no need for pip.

Comment: ah good call, hadn't realized ;)